# How to access the data in route in Angular4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have been trying to access the data in router from other component, but it always return undefined. let code talk.

```
import { Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    subPagetitle:string = 'test1';
    constructor(private dataRouter:ActivatedRoute) {

    }
    ngOnInit() :void{
        this.subPagetitle = this.dataRouter.snapshot.data['mydata'];
    }
}
```

in my routing component:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'paycheckDetail', component: PaycheckDetailComponent,data:{mydata:'test'}}  
];
```

when I try to access the mydata with dataRouter.snapshot.data['mydata'], it returns undefined. any idea? BTW there is no error in console. 
Thanks very much for helping.

Comment: The component with the `data` is `PaycheckDetailComponent` according to the routes config, yet you are trying to access the `data` in the `AppComponent`. Did you include the right code in your post?

Comment: Think it should be dataRouter.snapshot.data[0]?

Comment: @R.Richards this is what I am trying to do, I want to access that data from other components.

Comment: @linyuanxie you just can't data set on a route is for the component of that route. But you can just use `this.subPagetitle = 'test'`.

Comment: @JBNizet I searched online, there are some way I can access the data from component, even it is not defined in that component, just like what we do in angularjs1. I can't find what kind of problem I have in my code:(

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to `data` observable of `ActivatedRoute`:

```
class TheComponent {
  constructor(ar: ActivatedRoute) {
    ar.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.myData = data.mydata;
    });
}
```

More info from official docs is [here](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) and [there](https://angular.io/guide/router).